# Creating and Updating a User

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have one form for the edit and create for a user. On the form I have an if statement that if the form is an edit then it places a hidden form element that holds the value of the user being updated.

When I value the form on the php side controller this is what I'm using to do it with.

```
$user_id = $this->input->post('user_id');
if (isset($user_id_id))
{
$this->form_validation->set_rules('user_id', 'User ID', 'required|trim|xss_clean|integer');
}
```

I have not tested this on the edit form but on the add form it is saying that the user id is requred and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Your question is not clear can you show us the error and also the view code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use

```
if($this->input->post('user_id'))
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_id', 'User ID', 'required|trim|xss_clean|integer');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In CodeIgniter, `$this->input->post('foobar')` returns the value of `$_POST['foobar']` if it exists, or a `false` if it doesn't. Either ways, a value is set, and so [`isset()` will evaluate to a true](http://codepad.org/2tEj38i3).

Use `if ($user_id !== FALSE)` instead.